# Translating python line to c++ opencv

Tags: c++, python, opencv

I am currently working to translate a Python program to C++ I have converted over 98% of the program to C++, however there's one line I am stuck on. I'm currently using OpenCV and I believe it has something to do with that.
Python Line:

```
      for box in self.Boxes[:]:
               Cropped_Box = image.crop(box)
               mean = ImageStat.Stat(Cropped_Box).mean
```

C++ line:

```
      for(int a = 0; a < 24; a++)
                Average_reds = cv::mean(roi[a])
```

Average_reds is a `cv::Scalar` and I am trying to read gps times from an LED indicator light board. how I don't know if I using the same `mean` function in C++ as was used in Python.
Also, `Cropped_Box` and `roi[a]` are of course cropped region of an image of `Mat` type.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I want is there a translation from the python line ImageState.(box).mean to C++ I used cv::mean() but I am not sure if those two lines are the same. If not what is the c++ equilavent?

Comment: Do you have a documentation for ImageStat mean? cv::mean is well-documented: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=mean#cv2.mean

Comment: i do not but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **YES**, `cv::mean()` performs the same operation as `ImageStat.mean`. They both perform the channel-wise average of pixel values.

There is a slight difference: `ImageStat.mean` returns a list of averages for each channel. So a three-channel image will return a three-element list. `cv::mean()` always returns a `cv::Scalar`, which has four elements. This means that if the image has fewer than four channels, only the first N elements of the `cv::Scalar` (where N is the number of image channels) will have meaningful numbers.